# although page refreshed and url changed, page has same view. laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

home.blad.php

```
@foreach($profiles as $profile)
    @if(Auth::user()->email == $profile->email && Auth::user())             
        <a href="{{ url('write') }}"  class="write">WRITE</a>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('write', 'HomeController@write');
```

HomeController.php

```
public function write()
{
    return view('write');
}
```

write.blade.php has no content. when I click this link page seem to be changed ,but page doesn't change. just url is changed . how can I redirect write.blade.php ?

Comment: make sure that your write.blade.php is inside resources/view.

Comment: @vipul sorathiya sure.

Comment: Compare actual view url of "write.blade.php" and generated href in your anchor.

Comment: Paste your full HomeController and also write something in write.blade.php just for debugging

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if you posted your complete home controller.

If you are getting the same home page contents for all urls. You might not have enabled the nginx/apache rewriting properly.